# Spring bean creation exception for Maven transitive dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have a dependency hierarchy like this.

```
Module A

Module  B -> Maven Dependency on Proj A

Module C -> Maven Dependency on Proj B
```

Module C creates my war file. The build happens successfully. In Module C, I have the spring configuration file. There beans from Module B are created here. But one class in Module B, has a dependency on a class from Module A. That bean creation is now failing,during server start up, with "No Class found error" for this transitive dependency.

This happens only with Eclipse workspace resolution. If I remove that, proj is fine. Also if i explicitly add Module A as dependency to Module C, the error is fixed.

Is there a way to over come this in eclipse?

Comment: These projects added into eclipse as maven projects? If no then you probably need to regenerate eclipse project files.

Comment: Yes.. added. if i resolve dependencies by jar files and not by project,then it works.